# Прописать css если в ссылке стоит знак "#"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли прописать в `css` для ссылки, если в ней будет стоять `#`? Хочу отключить ссылку с `#` путем a `pointer-events:none;`. Есть ли способы через `js` или `jQuery`?

```html
<li class="item">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
</li>
<li class="item">
  <a href="site.com/url">Рабочая ссылка</a>
</li>
```

Comment: css - `a[href="#"] { pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший вариант указал [InDevX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285328/#comment2266013_1285328) в комментарии.

Но если вдруг надо это сделать на **JS**, то вот:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#"]').forEach(function(e) {
  e.style.cssText = 'pointer-events: none;';
});
```

И на про запас, аналогичный вариант на **jQuery**:

```
$('a[href="#"]').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```